# Creating Highcharts with Angular using Highcharts >= 5.0.0 and highcharts-ng >= 1.0.0 using a ChartFactory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I would like to **make the transition from pre-version 5.0.0 Highcharts and highcharts-ng version 0.0.12 to the latest versions**.

I know there are some critical changes in the chart object, as well as with how highcharts-ng works in the latest versions. I have been searching for an example on how to set my Angular environment up using these latest versions, but it seems there is a great shortage on resources using these versions.

I was hoping you could help me with setting this up.

I have tried numerous changes myself, but I keep getting errors I did not get with the older versions of the scripts. Errors such as:

1. `"Unable to get property of 'series' of undefined or null reference
   (at $doCheck
   (http://localhost:50262/app/vendorScripts/highcharts-ng.js:51:16))"`,
2. `"Cannot set property 'getChartObj' of undefined" (at HighChartNGController.$onInit (highcharts-ng.js:36))`,
3. `"Multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode (ChartFactory)`"

**This is my working solution pre-latest versions:**

**Here is my ChartFactory:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('portalDashboardApp')
  .factory('ChartFactory', function () {

      return {
          getChartConfig: function () {
              return {
                  options: {
                      chart: {
                          type: 'bar',
                          height: 400,
                          spacingTop: 30,
                          spacingBottom: 10,
                          spacingLeft: 10,
                          spacingRight: 50,
                          zoomType: 'x',
                          backgroundColor: false,
                          resetZoomButton: {
                              position: {
                                  x: 0,
                                  y: 40
                              }
                          }
                      },
                      credits: {
                          enabled: false
                      },
                      navigation: {
                          buttonOptions: {
                              y: -30
                          }
                      },
                      tooltip: {
                          formatter: function () {
                              return '<b>' + this.y + ' ' + this.series.name + '</b>';
                          }
                      },
                      plotOptions: {
                          column: {
                              stacking: ''
                          },
                          pie: {
                              allowPointSelect: true,
                              cursor: 'pointer',
                              dataLabels: {
                                  enabled: true,
                              },
                              showInLegend: true
                          },
                          series: {
                              animation: true,
                              point: {
                                  events: {
                                      click: function () {

                                      }
                                  }
                              },
                              dataLabels: {
                                  enabled: true,
                                  format: ''
                              }
                          }
                      },
                      exporting: {
                          sourceWidth: 1600,
                          sourceHeight: 800,
                          // scale: 2 (default)
                          chartOptions: {
                              subtitle: null
                          },
                          buttons: {
                              contextButton: {
                                  text: 'Export Chart'
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  },
                  title: {
                      text: false
                  },
                  xAxis: {
                      type: 'category'
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                      gridLineWidth: 1,
                      title: {
                          text: 'Count'
                      },
                      labels:
                      {
                          enabled: true,
                          format: '{value}'
                      }
                  },
                  legend: {
                      layout: 'vertical',
                      floating: true,
                      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                      align: 'right',
                      verticalAlign: 'top',
                      y: 60,
                      x: -60
                  },
                  series: [{}],
                  loading: false
              };
          }
      };
  });
```

**This is how I would create a chart in my Angular controller:**

1. I would inject my ChartFactory
2. Get my data from mt API call

**And then set up, customize and apply my data for my chart using these methods:**

```
function volumeGraphConfig(timeline_data, time_trend) {
    $scope.VolumeGraphChartConfig = ChartFactory.getChartConfig();
    $scope.VolumeGraphChartConfig.chart.type = 'column';
}

function populateVolumeData(timeline_data, time_trend) {

    $scope.VolumeGraphChartConfig.xAxis.categories = timeline_data;

    $scope.VolumeGraphChartConfig.series = [{
        name: 'Twitter',
        data: time_trend.Twitter,
        color: twitterColor
    }, {
        name: 'Instagram',
        data: time_trend.Instagram,
        color: instagramColor
    }, {
        name: 'Youtube',
        data: time_trend.Youtube,
        color: youtubeColor
    }];

    $scope.VolumeGraphChartConfig.tooltip = {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <strong>{point.y}</strong> mentions<br/>',
        shared: false
    };
}
```

**I would then display my chart using this HTML div:**

```
<highchart id="FacebookVolume" config="volumeGraphChartConfig"></highchart>
```

**How can I change this to work with the latest versions?** Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two errors:

`Cannot set property 'getChartObj' of undefined`

`Unable to get property of 'series' of undefined or null reference`

happen when your config object is undefined.

---

For your case, you need to use the same variable you declared on your `$scope`

```
<highchart id="FacebookVolume" config="VolumeGraphChartConfig"></highchart>
```

(capital **V**)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will give it a shot. Do you make use of  Highcharts > 5.0.0 and highcharts-ng  > 1.0.0? If so, perhaps you are willing to share an example setup?

Comment: I'm not yet using highcharts-ng 1.x, however I do note in 1.x+ the configuration object has changed to match highcharts JSON layout instead of their own version (in case thats what you are now bumping into).  In their changelog: "Now supports vanilla Highcharts config" (So all of these types of issues should go away: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/51#issuecomment-281848121 )

Comment: Yes, I also noted that. Thanks for the feedback and follow-up after so long!